# How to Interpret global test for interaction p-value

Tags: regression, interaction

I fit a regression model appropriate for a 3 x 3 factorial experiment with main effects for treatment and dose and the treatment-by-dose interaction, and obtain the following output:

```
reg y i.trt##i.dose

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =     360
-------------+------------------------------           F(  8,   351) =   15.07
   Model |  215829.772     8  26978.7215           Prob > F      =  0.0000
Residual |  628242.952   351  1789.86596           R-squared     =  0.2557
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.2387
   Total |  844072.723   359   2351.1775           Root MSE      =  42.307

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     trt |
      B  |   18.49209    9.46009     1.95   0.051    -.1135028    37.09768
      C  |   26.74031    9.46009     2.83   0.005     8.134718     45.3459
         |
    dose |
    100  |   18.37686    9.46009     1.94   0.053    -.2287271    36.98245
    300  |   34.14773    9.46009     3.61   0.000     15.54214    52.75332
         |
trt#dose |
  B#100  |  -7.225727   13.37859    -0.54   0.589      -33.538    19.08655
  B#300  |   8.602226   13.37859     0.64   0.521    -17.71005     34.9145
  C#100  |  -.8174986   13.37859    -0.06   0.951    -27.12978    25.49478
  C#300  |   26.57507   13.37859     1.99   0.048     .2627905    52.88734
         |
   _cons |   121.6413   6.689294    18.18   0.000     108.4852    134.7974
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

then use stata testparm command get global test for interaction p-value = 0.22

```
testparm i.trt#i.dose

 ( 1)  2.trt#100.dose = 0
 ( 2)  2.trt#300.dose = 0
 ( 3)  3.trt#100.dose = 0
 ( 4)  3.trt#300.dose = 0

   F(  4,   351) =    1.45
        Prob > F =    0.2179
```

However, how can I explain this p-value 0.22 in normal language? And p-value for C#300 is 0.048 (< 0.05) is significant, but global interaction p=0.22 is not significant, how should I interpret this contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

The test generated from `testparm` appears to be testing whether each value of the interaction is equal to zero using the previously estimated model. In your case, `i.trt##i.dose` estimates the dependent variable `y` from the main effects and the interaction of treatment and dose. The code `testparm i.trt#i.dose` may be evaluating only the interaction term without the main effects present in the model.

I could produce discrepant p-values from a fully parameterized model as compared to an interaction only model using the `auto` data:

```
set more off
clear
sysuse auto

egen mpg_cat = cut(mpg), at(12,18,20,25,41)

*regress the main effects
reg price i.mpg_cat i.foreign
    estat ic

*regress the dummy-coded interaction only
reg price i.mpg_cat#i.foreign
    estat ic 
testparm i.mpg_cat#i.foreign

*regress the main effects and the dummy-coded interaction
reg price i.mpg_cat##i.foreign
    estat ic 
testparm i.mpg_cat#i.foreign
testparm i.mpg_cat##i.foreign
```

You may want to consider use of the Akaike Information Criterion (provided by `estat ic` following your regression, as above) or other likelihood test to evaluate the significance of the interaction effect.